# В чем разница между локальной переменной и переменной экземпляра?

Tags: java

Я не могу понять разницу между локальной переменной и переменной экземпляра. В чем разница между локальной переменной и переменной экземпляра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Temp{
 int a; // переменная экземпляра, будет доступна у объектов типа Temp (new Temp().a)

 void someFunc(){
  int b; // доступна только внутри функции someFunc
 }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ты действительно помог мне.